# File manager not following system preferences

Tags: unity, 14.04, files, filemanager, preferences

The menu bar of my file manager is in the window and all other applications have it in the system bar. How do I fix this issue?

Image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPqrd.jpg

Comment: Make sure you do have global menu turned on.

Comment: @ElefantPhace how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried some practice on `nautilus` and here is result found:

- If `nautilus` is run without `sudo`, then it is ok with behaviour of
  menu-bar.
- **But if run `sudo nautilus` then menu-bar always under titile-bar. (say it is not actually menubar!)**

So use `nautilus` without `sudo` which follows right preference for actually `menu-bar`!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Appearance > Behavior and chose to show menus in the menu bar. It appears you may have some other setting though affecting this.

You can also take a screenshot by pressing the PrntScr button on your keyboard

Comment: I don't have wifi right now. It was the best i could do